# how can i add a loader while angular loads json data

Tags: json, angular, spinner, loader

here is my code for obtaining the data in angular,
I am trying to make it more friendly for users and it takes a while to load, I am looking for a way to add a loader in angular I am new to angular.

I am using ionic cli to build a mobile app feed by json data

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-articlespage',
  templateUrl: './articlespage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articlespage.page.scss'],
})
export class ArticlespagePage implements OnInit {


    //id : any[];
    title : any[];
    author : any[];
    date : any[];
    content : any[];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Remote Data:" + JSON.stringify(data));
      //console.log(data);
      this.parseJson(data);
    });
  }

  parseJson(data)
  {
     let jsonArray = data;

    //this.id = [];
    this.title = [];
    this.author = [];
    this.date = [];
    this.content = [];

    for(let i=0; i< jsonArray.length ; i++)
    {
       let jsonObject = jsonArray[i];
       //this.id.push(jsonObject.id);
       this.title.push(jsonObject.title);
       this.author.push(jsonObject.author.name);
       this.date.push(jsonObject.created_at );
       this.content.push(jsonObject.blog_entry );

    }
  }



}
```

html:

```
  <ion-content fullscreen>
     <h2 > Articles </h2>
      <ion-card class="feedspotcard-1 box" *ngFor=" let item of title; let i = index;">
        <ion-card-content>
            <div class="box-shadow">
              <div class="coolbar"></div>
              <!-- <p> <span> Id : </span> <span innerHTML={{id[i]}}> </span> </p> -->
              <h4> <span innerHTML={{title[i]}}> </span> </h4>
              <p>  <span innerHTML={{content[i]}}> </span> </p>
              <p> <span> author : </span> <span innerHTML={{author[i]}}> </span> </p>
              <p> <span> date : </span> <span innerHTML={{date[i]}}> </span> </p>
            </div>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
```

not necessary but result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a property that keeps track of the state of the request. i.e. `loadingData: boolean`.

in your component you would need to set this value at the start of the request, and when it completes.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loading = true;
  this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data => {
    // set the status of loading to false so the template can update
    this.loading =f alse;
    console.log("Remote Data:" + JSON.stringify(data));
    //console.log(data);
    this.parseJson(data);
  });
}
```

finally, in the template, add an element that is shown based on the value of the `loading` property.

```
<div *ngIf="loading"><!-- Insert your progress message/animation --> </div>
```

Comment: this seems to work fine until i reload the server  i get this error :  ERROR in src/app/articlespage/articlespage.page.ts:21:10 - error TS2339: Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'ArticlespagePage'.
21     this.loading = true;
            ~~~~~~~
src/app/articlespage/articlespage.page.ts:24:10 - error TS2339: Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'ArticlespagePage'.
24     this.loading = false;

Comment: Ok i fixed this isssue by decalring the loading = "true" in the script befor the nd module thingy: export class ArticlespagePage implements OnInit {

    loading = true;

Comment: this implies that the property wasn't declared in the class. before the `constructor() {}`, if you add `loading: boolean = false;` this will ensure the  property is available upon initialization of the component. and you don't have to re-initialize it in OnInit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngx-spinner` as a loader. It works as follows.

First and foremost import NgxSpinnerModule in in the root module(AppModule)

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
// Import library module
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    NgxSpinnerModule
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Add `NgxSpinnerService` service wherever you want to use the ngx-spinner

```
 import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";
     
    class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {}
     
      ngOnInit() {
        /** spinner starts on init */
        this.spinner.show();
     
        setTimeout(() => {
          /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
          this.spinner.hide();
        }, 5000);
      }
    }
```

Use in your template.

```
 <ngx-spinner></ngx-spinner>
```